# sitefinity ControllerToolboxItem vs MVC Controller

Tags: sitefinity

I have built a MVC Controller that will be used throughout the site to download files for an API. I am not able to call it like normal with the Mvc\controllers\ControllerName\method. I get a 404 error page not found. I did do so testing with adding `ControllerToolboxItem` and adding it to a page. Once I add it to the page I can call the method. Using the `PageName\method?filePath=""` so I know the method is working. Is there something I am missing in my Controller that I need to add for it to be called throughout the site?

```
public class CommonController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDataFileResponse(string filePath) {
        try {
    
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            long fileLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
    
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "mydata.csv";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileLength;
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the widget to a base page template, so now it will be available on all pages.

Or see if you can make it an web api controller and then there will be no widget, but you will be able to access it via /yourapiroute/common/getdataFileResponse?filepath=xxx

I've written an article in the past, which might be of help: https://sitefinitydevelopment.com/blog/uploading-files-to-sitefinity-asynchronously-using-kendo-ui-upload.html

Comment: How would you know when to use the web api over the widget?

Comment: If you need the users to be able to drag it onto pages and maybe configure some of its properties - then a widget. If you want it to render html on the server - then a widget.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I dont see a Global page can is it something different?

Comment: You can add it if it’s not there